# Rolling Average Prediciton for Future 30 Days in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a forecasting graph that will be pulling in data from SQL through power query. The graph will have slicers and filters available to the user to analyze different populations. I am currently being asked to provide a rolling average for each day of the **next month** but will update daily as more data becomes available. I need 30 days of rolling average that occur after the current date. Using the prior days rolling average calculation. This has to be completed in dax to allow the filters and slicers to work appropriately. The rolling average looks 14 days back.

Any ideas on how to best proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a table of data to show how this looks in excel:

[image: Excel Example Table]

Comment: This is not achievable in dax Measure because of "A circular dependency".

Comment: I was worried about that.